# how to list faulty nodes in bst

Tags: binary-search-tree

So I was asked this question in recent coding round but could not figure out the approach and the solution.Tried google search but could not find any such question. Can someone please help

Question: Given a BST find all the faulty nodes in it. for example

```
                                                        9
                                                       / \
                                                      1   15
                                                         /
                                                        4
```

For above BST ans is [4,15] (faulty node as well as parent of faulty node i.e 4 is faulty and parent of 4 is 15)

```
    9
   / \
  3   121 
 /\     \
1  70    250
```

for this bst ans is [70,3]
could not think  of right approach

Comment: Which **node** is faulty is ambiguous. In the example the node 15 is certainly not faulty, so I don't understand why it should be in the output. You *could* say that node 4 is faulty, but you could also say it is right and that node 9 is faulty (and should for instance have been 2). So it is not clear what you are asking about. Secondly, the title of your question is asking about *removal*, so why then should [4, 15] be the output?

Comment: It still does not explain why the root is not considered the faulty node.

Answer (score 1):

A basic way to think about a solution to this problem is as follows:

- Traverse all nodes in this tree
- For each node, figure out if it is 'faulty'

Traversing a tree is a relatively simple, but you must decide whether you want to do [depth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

The other thing you would need to decide is how you would test a node to see if it is 'faulty'.  Thinking about what a binary tree structure is you could define characteristics of a valid (not 'faulty') node as:

- all node values in the left subtree are less than the value of the node
- all node values in the right subtree are greater than the value of the node
- is the root node *OR* all nodes in the node's subtree are less than the smallest ancestor node which contains the node in a left child subtree and greater than the greatest ancestor node which contains the node in a right child subtree

*Note: this assumes the fact that a node can only have two children (a left and a right) is part of the definition of a node*

This definition seems to fit your example. There could be other definitions - this isn't necessarily the most correct definition.  The important thing is to understand what the definition is and to be able to state it in as clear terms as you can

Framing the problem like this should make it easier to think about how to start coding a solution to this problem.  It should be relatively straightforward to use this outline of the problem to create a brute-force solution without needing any additional analysis of the problem.

There are many ways to solve this problem, but one way to go about it (which would be more efficient than a brute force method) would be to use depth-first search and recursion to check the faultiness of each node.  Some pseudocode might look like:

```
def checkTree(var root, var faultyNodes)
  // initiate depth-first search
  if (root.left)
    leftNodeInfo = checkNode(root.left, 0, root.value, faultyNodes)
  if (root.right)
    rightNodeInfo = checkNode(root.right, root.value, MAX_INT, faultyNodes)

  // check if root is faulty
  if ((root.left and leftNodeInfo["maxVal"] > root.value) or (root.right and rightNodeInfo["minVal"] > root.value))
    faultyNodes.add(root)
  
  // return all the faultyNodes
  return faultyNodes

def checkNode(node, maxLeftAncestor, minRightAncestor, faultyNodes)
  // continue depth-first search
  if (node.left)
    leftNodeInfo = checkNode(node.left, maxLeftAncestor, min(minLeftAncestor, node.value), faultyNodes)
    leftMax = leftNodeInfo["maxValue"]
    leftMin = leftNodeInfo["minValue"]
  else
    leftMax = 0
    leftMin = MAX_INT
  if (node.right)
    rightNodeInfo = checkNode(node.right, max(maxLeftAncestor, node.value), MAX_INT, faultyNodes)
    rightMax = rightNodeInfo["maxValue"]
    rightMin = rightNodeInfo["minValue"]
  else
    rightMax = 0
    rightMin = MAX_INT

  // check if node is faulty
  if ((node.left and leftNodeInfo["maxVal"] > node.value) or (node.right and rightNodeInfo["minVal"] > node.value) or maxLeftAncestor > node.value or minLeftAncestor < node.value)
    faultyNodes.add(root)

  // return max/min info
  return { "maxVal": max(node.value, leftMax, rightMax), "minVal": min(node.value, leftMax, rightMax) }
```

NOTE: the above codes assumes that two nodes in the tree have the same value and that all node values are integers between 0 and `MAX_INT`